# Calling async promises inside async promise using .join()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, bluebird

I´m using node/ epxress, mysql and bluebird.

I´m currently doing an async database operation after the client request it. Inside the callback of the first database operation I have to perform some calculations first and afterwards doing two more database queries which are required to provide the client the correct result.

My Code is separated into a Controller class, which handles the get/ post request. In the middle a service class for business logic, which talks to a database class which queries in the database.

I´m currently able to do perform the first and second database request.

```
getVacation(departmentID) {

        return departmentDatabase.getVacation(departmentID)
            .then(result => [ result, result.map(entry => this.getDateRange(new Date(entry.dateFrom), new Date(entry.dateTo))) ])
            .spread(function(result, dateRange){
                var mergedDateRange = [].concat.apply([], dateRange);
                var counts = {};
                mergedDateRange.forEach(function(x) { counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0)+1; });

                return [{"vacationRequest": result, "dateRange": dateRange, "countedDateRange": counts}];
            })
             .then( result => [result, departmentDatabase.countUser(departmentID)])
             .spread(function (result, userOfDepartmentCount){
                console.log(userOfDepartmentCount);
                console.log(result);
                //console.log(blocked);

                return departmentID; //return just for not running into timeout
            })
            .catch(err => {
                // ...do something with it...
                // If you want to propagate it:
                return Promise.reject(err);
                // Or you can do:
                // throw err;
            });
    }
```

But when trying to perform the third I´m running into trouble. 
For a solution of this problem I read the Bluebird Doc´s, which pointed me to `.all()` or (even better) `.join()`. But trying to use either of them didn´t worked for me.

If I try it with `.join()` is always results in `join is not a function`, which I find confusing because I can use all other function. I also tried to require

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var join = Promise.join;
```

But not even this helped.

> Currently I just require Bluebird as Promise in my database class.

So here now my entire service class.

```
'use strict';

var departmentDatabase = require('../database/department');
var moment = require('moment');

class DepartmentService {
    constructor() {
    }

    getVacation(departmentID) {

        return departmentDatabase.getVacation(departmentID)
            .then(result => [ result, result.map(entry => this.getDateRange(new Date(entry.dateFrom), new Date(entry.dateTo))) ])
            .spread(function(result, dateRange){
                var mergedDateRange = [].concat.apply([], dateRange);
                var counts = {};
                mergedDateRange.forEach(function(x) { counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0)+1; });

                return [{"vacationRequest": result, "dateRange": dateRange, "countedDateRange": counts}];
            })
            //THIS DOES NOT WORK
            .join(result => [result, departmentDatabase.countUser(departmentID), departmentDatabase.blockedDaysOfResponsible(departmentID)])
            .spread(function (result, userOfDepartmentCount, blocked){
                console.log(userOfDepartmentCount);
                console.log(result);
                console.log(blocked);

                return departmentID;
            })
            .catch(err => {
                // ...do something with it...
                // If you want to propagate it:
                return Promise.reject(err);
                // Or you can do:
                // throw err;
            });
    }

    getDateRange(startDate, stopDate) {
        var dateArray = [];
        var currentDate = moment(startDate);
        while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
            dateArray.push(moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
            currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'days');
        }

        return dateArray;
    }
}

module.exports = new DepartmentService();
```

Is someone able to give me an example how to do it right?

EDIT:

Here an example code I´m using inside my databaseCall, to return the db result and the promise

```
return Promise.using(dbConnection.getConnection(), function (conn) {
            return conn.queryAsync(sql, [departmentID])
                .then(function (result) {
                    return result;
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    return err;
                });
        });
```

Comment: So because you're using `.join()`, you're using the `Promise` that come out of the `getVacation` function - so it might be advantageous to see what it returns (ensuring it's a Bluebird Promise). Secondly the [docs](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.join.html) specify that Promises should be passed to `join`, so maybe your line should read `.then( (result) => Promise.join( Promise.resolve(result), departmentDatabase.countUser(departmentID), departmentDatabase.blockedDaysOfResponsible(departmentID), (a, b, c) => [a, b, c] ) )`

Comment: Or better yet, with `Promise.all`: `.then(result => Promise.all([result, departmentDatabase.countUser(departmentID), departmentDatabase.blockedDaysOfResponsible(departmentID)])]))`

Comment: I´m having some trouble with the syntax in your Promise.all example. Could you please formulate this as an answer, best with a example console.log(a);? that would help me a lot. The .join() example still runs into the `not a function` error

Comment: Ah got it. Do you want to create an answer for this, otherwise I will. `.then(result => Promise.all([result, departmentDatabase.countUser(departmentID), departmentDatabase.blockedDaysOfResponsible(departmentID)])).spread(function(a, b, c){
                console.log(a);
                console.log(b);
                console.log(c);

                return 1;
            })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Promise.join` is nice, but it might not suit your situation the best. `Promise.all` will combine several promises like you have there into a single resolution:

`.then(result => Promise.all([result, departmentDatabase.countUser(departmentID), departmentDatabase.blockedDaysOfResponsible(departmentID)])]‌​))`

Then you could spread that result (an array) into a function call:

```
.spread(function(a, b, c) {
    console.log("Results", a, b, c);
});
```

`Promise.all` takes an array of Promises, waits for all of them to resolve (or reject), and then continues with the results in an ordered array into the subsequent `.then` (or other promise) clause.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for a module that makes control flow with promises easier then you might like [relign](https://github.com/RobertWHurst/relign). `Promise.all` may do the trick here, but if you need the resolved results, then `relign.parallel` or `relign.series` might be better for you.